# Does oracle soa quick start installation needs oracle database installation or does it come with some embedded database?

Tags: oracle12c, osb, oracle-soa

I am new to oracle SOA products and learning.

I have installed the fusion middlewre 12.2.1.2.0 soa quick install distributin and I am wondering does it require any database. I know that in production architecture it certainly needs oracle database but as far as development environment is concerned which database does it come with ?

Also how to see/modify these files related with database configurations.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed the Oracle SOA Suite quick start then it comes with a pre-configured instance of Java DB, you don't need to have an Oracle database to start to use the suite, unless you have some special requirement.